# Query optimation for insert to database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization

I need a solution to insert a lot of rows in concurrent time in my sql DB.

I have a rule, that everytime I insert to my transaction table, I need a unique ID that's composed by currentTime+transactionSource+sequenceNumber. my problem is, when I test my service using Jmeter, the service is down when the concurrent insert process is up to 3000 rows. the problem relies on, the duplication of the unique ID I generate. so, there are some duplications. in my assumption, the duplication happen because a previous insert process hasnt finished, but there's another insert process. So,it generates unique ID duplication. 
Can anyone give me suggestion in what the best way for doing this? Thank you.

Comment: Could you please clarify which language you are using to do this?

Comment: How can you guarantee that the combination of currentTime + transactionSource + sequenceNumber is unique? What is "sequence number"? It's usually much better to use auto-increment or similar for unique keys....

Comment: I got lost in your explanation; give us some code and/or sample data.  For example, "concurrent insert process is up to 3000 rows" -- is that a single connection running a single `INSERT` of 3000 rows?  or 3000 connections stumbling over each other inserting one row?  Is that one row at the same spot in the table?  Is the table InnoDB?  Etc.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has three wonderful methods to ensure that an id is unique:

- `auto_increment` columns
- `uuid()`
- `uuid_short()`

Use them!  The most common way to implement a unique id is the first one:

```
create table t (
    t_id int auto_increment primar key,
    . . .
)
```

I strongly, strongly advise you not to maintain your own id.  You get race conditions (as you have seen).  Your code will be less efficient than the code in the database.  If you need the separate components, you can implement them as *columns* in the table.

In other words, your fundamental problem is your "rule".  And there are zillions of databases in the world that work perfectly well without such a rule.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you let the database handle the insert id and then update the row with a secondary field containing the format you want ? If you have dupplicates, you can always append the row id to this identifier so it will always be unique.